# Use gsub to keep only the first part of my string

Tags: r, string, gsub

In R, I have strings looking like:

```
test <- 'ZYG11B|79699'
```

I want to keep only `'ZYG11B'`.

My best attempt yet:

```
gsub ("|.*$", "", test) # should replace everything after '|' by nothing
```

but returns

```
> [1] ""
```

How should I do that?

Comment: simply escape the `|`, i.e. `gsub ("\\|.*$", "", test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a protected character which means it should be enclosed in square brackets or escaped with double slashes:

```
> gsub('[|].*$','', test)
[1] "ZYG11B"
> gsub('\\|.*$','', test)
[1] "ZYG11B"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(test, "\\w+")
#[1] "ZYG11B"
```